# PHP ADOdb not respecting autoCommit=false

Tags: php, transactions, commit, adodb, autocommit

I have the following code

```
<?php
include("adodb5/adodb.inc.php"); // includes the adodb library

$db = NewADOConnection('mysql'); // A new connection
$conn = $db->Connect("localhost", "test", "password", "test_db");

if(!$conn){
  echo 'failed to connect'; die();
}else{

    $db->autoCommit = false;
    $db->StartTrans();

    $statement1 = $db->Prepare("insert into table1 (cod) values (1)");
    $ok1 = $db->Execute($statement1);

    $statement2 = $db->Prepare("insert into table2AAAAA (cod) values (1)");
    $ok2 = $db->Execute($statement2);

    $statement3 = $db->Prepare("insert into table3 (cod) values (1)");
    $ok3 = $db->Execute($statement2);

    if(!$ok1){
        echo 'Failed 1';
        $db->FailTrans();
    }else if(!$ok2){
        echo 'Failed 2';
        $db->FailTrans();
    }else if(!$ok3){
        echo 'Failed 3';
        $db->FailTrans();
    }else if($ok1 && $ok2 && $ok3){ //ONLY IF ALL ARE OK THEN COMMIT
        $db->CompleteTrans();
    }

}
?>
```

I am forcing an error on $statement2 and when I run the code I get 'Failed 2' as output but the problem is that  $statement1 is executed and the record is inserted in the DB.

All I want is for the statements to commit ONLY if all of them don't fail.
$db->autoCommit = false; -- Doesn't seem to be working?

I'd appreciate if you could point me out for a solution.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Note that the $autoCommit variable is noted as being "private, do not modify":

https://github.com/ADOdb/ADOdb/blob/master/adodb.inc.php#L433

ADODB's "mysql" driver doesn't appear to have any transaction support at all; if you're using a more recent release, ADODB's "mysqli" driver supports BeginTrans(), CommitTrans(), and co; see http://adodb.sourceforge.net/docs-adodb.htm#starttrans for documentation on these functions.